# Can javascript get a function from another js file using node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm working on a program that needs reading a file. I have a file `index.js` with a function that starts like this:

```
function read(file){

    var lines = parse(file);
```

and I have another file `server.js` with the `parse(file)` function:

```
function parse(file){

    var fs = require('fs');

    var contents = fs.readFileSync(file, 'utf8');
    return contents.split('\n');

}
```

The `index.js` file is in a `public` folder in the project folder of `server.js`, like this:

```
/project
...server.js
.../public
    ...index.js
```

And it must remain like that.
So my question is why can't I read the function from the `server.js` file and how can I do it.

Comment: You can use `module.exports` to export function and then you can import it using `require`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself".

Answer (score 0):

export the function in `index.js` via

```
module.exports = function parse(file){

  var fs = require('fs');

  var contents = fs.readFileSync(file, 'utf8');
  return contents.split('\n');

}
```

And import it in server.js like

```
var parse = require('./public')
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

checkout [nodejs modules](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html), which allow you to export and import parts of your code between files.

In your case, it would be

```
// ./index.js

var myFunction = require('./public')
```

and

```
// ./public/index.js

module.exports = function iCanBeAnonymousOrNamed() {
   return 'do something'
}
```

Comment: i get 'Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined' when I try to run index.js... the index.js is not node.js...

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is make your `parse` function a method on an object which you can then export using `module.exports = parseModule` - then you can import this module using `require` from within your index.js file i.e. `var parseModule = require('./parseModule')`